# How to backup sql Database from FrontEnd

Tags: asp.net, sql, .net

We have two Server's

In one server Application(ASP.net Website) is Running and In Second server Database(SQL 2005) is running..

Previously both Application and Database running on Same Server and I can make backup using this command

backup database TESTDBNAME to disk='PATH'

can someone suggest me how i can get rid of current situation

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why this doesn't work now? What situation are we trying to get rid of?

Answer (score 0):

The `path` is considered to be from the server where your DB is stored. So you may not be able to access the path from that server since your files are stored on other server. You can create sql query with data option  and save into your local machine. See [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/07/sql-server-2008-2008-r2-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-data-schema-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects) for help.